# Change TinyMCE image upload relative URL

Tags: url, tinymce, relative-path

I'm using tinymce on Laravel, my upload path is `/upload/img.jpg`
but when I save my form to database, tinymce convert the URL to relative one to `../upload`, how to change this relative URL  from `../upload` to `/upload`

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this same issue today. You can solve this by setting the `relative_urls` configuration option to false when initializing your tinymce instance:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#targetElement",
    [...]
    relative_urls: false,
})
```

This was buried in the documentation at: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/#relative_urls

Answer (score -1):

TinyMCE has a variety of settings that impact how URLs are handled.  The documentation site lists them all here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

I would look at how you have TinyMCE configured and determine which of these settings will get you the end result you desire.

Comment: this is not an answer, this is a link to the documentation